# Coersivity of a bilinear form

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I need to proof the coersivity of the following bilinear form. a,b and c are scalars, u is the velocity vector field and p is the pressure. Any help is much appreciated!

$$ B(\textbf{u},\textbf{v}) = a (\textbf{u},\textbf{v}) - (\textbf{u},b \cdot \nabla \textbf{v}) - c (p, div \, \textbf{v}) $$

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? On what kind of space is $B$ defined, does scalar mean real or complex, what does pressure mean, what is $\nabla$, what are the round brackets?